# Form builder with voice messaging

Tags: forms, voicemail

I am looking for a form builder, where with each question, the user would have two options (two tabs) to reply either in text or by leaving a text message.

The only form builder with an option for leaving a voice message, that I have found so far is Jotform. But unfortunately, it does not have the tabbed answer options feature.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out Jotform has a workaround for this by using conditional logic. Example: https://form.jotform.com/210516948475059